# Compiling LuaSocket: Cannot open file: 'string.h'

Tags: lua, luasocket, luarocks

The log:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>luarocks install luasocket
Installing https://luarocks.org/luasocket-3.0rc1-2.src.rock...
Using https://luarocks.org/luasocket-3.0rc1-2.src.rock... switching to 'build' mode
cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Fosrc/mime.obj -Ic:/lua/include/ src/mime.c -DLUA_COMPAT_APIINTCASTS -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DNDEBUG -DLUASOCKET_API=__declspec(dllexport) -DMIME_API=__declspec(dllexport)
mime.c
src/mime.c(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string.h': No such file or directory

Error: Build error: Failed compiling object src/mime.obj
```

I'm very new to the whole LuaRocks thing, so I have no idea how to go about fixing this.

Comment: Did you use the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" from the start menu to start your DOS box?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-complete guide to get you started on installing lua modules from a fresh Windows 7.

1) We need LuaRocks in order to install Lua dependencies automatically (similar to cpan/cpanm in Perl or pip in Python). Download LuaRocks by grabbing the latest version with a "-win32.zip" suffix from here: http://keplerproject.github.io/luarocks/releases/

At the time of this writing, this is the following file: http://keplerproject.github.io/luarocks/releases/luarocks-2.3.0-win32.zip

2) Unzip it into a new directory and install it with `install.bat /L`. Without the "/L" flag, it will complain that it cannot find your existing Lua installation. With the flag, it will just install a new Lua binary (version 5.1). LuaRocks is now installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks`. You may now delete the extracted "luarocks-2.3.0-win32" directory.

3) In order to compile and install modules, we will need a C++ compiler. Download and install the Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 from here: http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

(We want this so that we can avoiding installing the huge, multi-gigabyte Visual Studio 2015.)

4) Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools`. Right click on "Visual C++ 2015 x86 Native Build Tools Command Prompt", and select "Run as administrator".

5) Run the following command: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\luarocks.bat" install luasocket`.

Note that you may have to install additional stuff for certain modules. And sometimes, modules are simply unable to be compiled on Windows at all.

Comment: I wonder how to install LuaRocks on Windows at the moment. I found there http://luarocks.github.io/luarocks/releases/ file luarocks-3.1.3-windows-32.zip (luarocks.exe stand-alone Windows binary). And zip has just two exe - luarocks.exe and luarocks-admin.exe. There is no install.bat :-/